# Missing "Appendix" in appendix title when using KOMA-Script class (scrreport)

Tags: koma-script, appendices

**Problem description:**

Recently I moved to the KOMA-Script class

> scrreport

to get rid of the

> Chapter 1...

extra in the Titles.

This however also changed my appendix to the Format

> A. Titlename

Ideally I would like it to look like this:

> Appendix A. Titlename

all in one line, or at least get the Chapter format from the report class.

I tried the appendix package like this:

```
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
```

but this does not seem to work for the scrreport class.

So far I was only able to add an extra page with the word Appendix (in my language Anhang) like this:

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
```

While the appendix layout looks like this:

```
%Anhang/appendix
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Anhang}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anhang}

\begin{appendices}

    %remove entries from the list of figures
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

    \input{Anhang}

    %set it back to 1 otherwise the toc will be missing entries
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

\end{appendices}
```

**Question**:

So how can I get the missing word "Appendix" before the ".A"
back while staying with the scrreport class ?

**Additional Information:**

It should also be noted that I do not want the listoffigures to contain anything but the word

> Appendix

(in my language Anhang) as you can see when you look at the latex code below.

**Minimal working example**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{scrreprt}

\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}


\begin{document}

%Anhang /appendix
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Anhang}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anhang}
\begin{appendices}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
    \chapter{Some apendix heading}
    %set it back to 1 otherwise the toc will be missing entries
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}   
\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

This will produce (instead of Appendix A):

[image]

Comment: Does `appendixprefix=true` (as a documentclass option) produce the desired results?

Comment: sadly no, do I have to change something else as well to use this option properly ?

Comment: Also if you use `\appendix` instead of the `appendices` environment? However, it is somewhat hard to assist you, because the code you provided above we cannot compile, for we miss the inputed files, your bib entries and so on. If this does not work, please take a look on how to build a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: yes I tried \appendix but it did not work either, you are right, I will try to create a MWE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the documentclass option `appendixprefix`.
This alone will not work, because in `scrreprt`, you have to mark your appendix with `\appendix`. So in your MWE this would be

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany,appendixprefix]{scrreprt}

\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}


\begin{document}

\appendix
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Anhang}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anhang}
\begin{appendices}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
    \chapter{Some apendix heading}
    %set it back to 1 otherwise the toc will be missing entries
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}   
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

This prints Appendix A on a separate line. To get "Appendix A. Titlename" in one line, you can modify `\thechapter` instead: (You should still use `\appendix`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{scrreprt}

\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\begin{document}

\appendix
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Anhang}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anhang}
\begin{appendices}
    \renewcommand\thechapter{\appendixname\space\Alph{chapter}}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
    \chapter{Some apendix heading}
    %set it back to 1 otherwise the toc will be missing entries
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}   
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

This results in [image: The resulting title]

Comment: My old example was designed to use a phantom page for the entry "Anhang" in the table of content, so could you either set {tocdepth}{-1} to 0 or add a note for others who might read this ?

Comment: just realized that you also  answered the question on how to put it in one line, thanks again

Answer (score 5):

> Too long for a comment.

I'm not sure what is going wrong with your full document. Your example is still very far from "minimal". Take a look at the following simple document and see if it helps you figure out what's wrong with your own document:

```
\documentclass[appendixprefix=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A regular chapter}

\appendix
\chapter{Some apendix heading}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: If I may guess on what might be going wrong, I'd bet on the following passage of the `appendix` package documentation: "Depending on the particular package options that are set and the document class, the `appendices` environment may change the definition of elements of the sectioning commands (e.g., `\chapter` or `\section`). This may be a problem if the environment is used in conjunction with any other package that makes changes to these commands."

Comment: I tested this, the problem was that I had to use \appendix together with the option appendixprefix in the documentclass options. I did try each of them before but never together.